# Initializing inflate state

Tags: android

```
class IconicAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    Activity context=new Activity();

    IconicAdapter(Activity context) {
        super(context, R.layout.topic_list_row, itemList);
        this.context = context;
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    }
```

---

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //  View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;
                 LayoutInflater inflater = null;

        if (convertView == null) {



                 convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.topic_list_row, null);

             holder = new ViewHolder();
             holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);
             convertView.setTag(holder);
         } else {
             holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
         }
             Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "MS-I034.TTF");
             holder.textView.setTypeface(face);
             holder.textView.setText(getModel(position));

        return convertView;
    }
```

Error:

```
05-02 11:29:53.010: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1043): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-02 11:29:53.010: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1043): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-02 11:29:53.010: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at com.webrich.bachflower.Topics$IconicAdapter.getView(Topics.java:113)
05-02 11:29:53.010: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1430)
05-02 11:29:53.010: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1216)
05-02 11:29:53.010: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1127)
05-02 11:29:53.010: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
05-02 11:29:53.010: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:581)
05-02 11:29:53.010: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:365)
05-02 11:29:53.010: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
05-02 11:29:53.010: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
05-02 11:29:53.010: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
05-02 11:29:53.010: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
05-02 11:29:53.010: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:531)
05-02 11:29:53.010: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
05-02 11:29:53.010: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
05-02 11:29:53.010: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
05-02 11:29:53.010: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
05-02 11:29:53.010: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
05-02 11:29:53.010: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:839)
05-02 11:29:53.010: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
05-02 11:29:53.010: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-02 11:29:53.010: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-02 11:29:53.010: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-02 11:29:53.010: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-02 11:29:53.010: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-02 11:29:53.010: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-02 11:29:53.010: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-02 11:29:53.010: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1043):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: It would be nice if you wrote a friendly description of your problem, so that a human being can relate to it... not just a computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
//  View row = convertView;
ViewHolder holder = null;
  LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
if (convertView == null) {

         convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.topic_list_row, null);

     holder = new ViewHolder();
     holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);
     convertView.setTag(holder);
 } else {
     holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
 }
     Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "MS-I034.TTF");
     holder.textView.setTypeface(face);
     holder.textView.setText(getModel(position));

return convertView;
```

}

Comment: same issue no change even i changed as above

Comment: No when i run my app am getting this continuosly and if i move to next activity from this and if i come back again to this its showing same number of times intializing inflate state

Comment: make constructor of that class in add this line in constructor  LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater(); and remove in getView()..

Comment: if i remove that line in getview its showing to create local variable inflater in getview().

Comment: class IconicAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
 Activity context=new Activity();

 IconicAdapter(Activity context) {
  super(context, R.layout.topic_list_row, itemList);
  this.context = context;
  LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
 }

Comment: so create local variable for LayoutInflater inflater;

Comment: if i create ,its asking to initialize inflater variable.

Comment: then what is the use of declaring in constructor?

Comment: so initialize is with null.. when u declare in getView() so it it inflate many time but i want it only one time so declare in constructor.. getting..?

Comment: its showing null pointer exception pls check above i updated logcat

Comment: i didnt fine new log.. plz add your all code here and give me link

Comment: after did the change watever u said  also  am getting null pointer exception

Comment: in getview method , convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.topic_list_row, null

Comment: of ohhh . we forgot to remove this line "LayoutInflater inflater=null;" in getView().. remove this n check n let me know what happens...

Comment: 05-02 12:35:44.880: DEBUG/szipinf(2822): Initializing inflate state
05-02 12:35:44.950: DEBUG/szipinf(2822): Initializing inflate state
e

Comment: 10 times which i got before same Intializing inflate state